# Submitting JSON data to MVC controller. Why does it not handle complex types?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, version-control, post, complextype

Define C# helper classes as:

`
                public class SelectedFiles 
        {
            public string Host { get; set; }

```
        public List<SelectedFile> Files { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelectedFile
    {

        public string ShortName {get; set;}

        public string Category { get; set; }


    }`
```

And let define two controller methods (+ Deserialize helper):

```
    private SelectedFiles Deserialize(string json)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SelectedFiles));
            return (SelectedFiles) serializer.ReadObject(stream);               
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// MVC seems to be incapable to deserizalize complex types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedFilesJSON"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void UploadFiles(SelectedFiles selectedFilesJSON)
    {
        var result = selectedFilesJSON;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedFilesJSON"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void UploadFilesJSON(string selectedFilesJSON)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedFilesJSON))
        {
            var result = this.Deserialize(selectedFilesJSON);

        }           

    }
```

With javascript calling

```
        var SelectedFiles = [];
        var SelectedFile;

        selectedCheckBoxes.each(function(idx, element){
            SelectedFile = {ShortName: element.value, Category: "a category"};                
            SelectedFiles.push(SelectedFile);
        });            

        var selectedFileMessage = {};
        selectedFileMessage.Host = "test"
        selectedFileMessage.Files = SelectedFiles;

        var message = $.toJSON(selectedFileMessage);            


        $.ajax({url:"UploadFilesJSON", type:'POST', traditional:true,  data: { selectedFilesJSON : message } , success: function(result){ alert(result);} });            

        $.ajax({url:"UploadFiles", type:'POST', traditional:true,  data: { selectedFilesJSON : selectedFileMessage } , success: function(result){ alert(result);} });
```

The first .ajax POST method will work. Basically dumping the serialized JSON object as a string to the controller method.

The second .ajax POST does not work. It does not seems to figure out how to deserialize the 'SelectedFiles' helper class from the argument list.

One word: 'Flabergasted'

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: The question is "Why does this not work"? Am I missing something trivial? Is this a known restriction on MVC part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tagged your question with ASP.NET MVC 2, if that is correct you don't have JSON binding support out of the box. JsonValueProviderFactory is available since ASP.NET MVC 3. To bind JSON in previous versions of ASP.NET MVC you need to create a value provider or model binder. You can read more about it here: [Sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

Comment: Thanks tpeczek. You noted the MVC 2 tag correctly. This hidden feature is solving the problmen!

Answer (score 0):

In the second case the expected post data is the collection of SelectedFile. Have you tried

```
$.ajax({url:"UploadFiles", type:'POST', traditional:true,  data: SelectedFiles, success: function(result){ alert(result);} });
```

Comment: I did, but no luck. Invoking it that way was also my first intuition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your POSTs contentType as json. Also, MVC will modelbind to your model so you don't need to use a string as an action parameter. Phil Haack has an [example](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) on his blog.